# Clearing npm git remotes

Tags: git, npm

We run npm builds on a schedule, and we ran out of disk space due to npm pulling git dependencies into folders like:

`%AppData%\Temp\npm-31235-4b3b79e1\git-cache-2c0066f6ed57`

Looking at some [issues and commits](https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/6823807bba6c00228a724e1205ae90d67df0adad) to npm this is by design but without any method to clear them out? These are now taking up many GBs of space. `npm cache clean` will not remove these files. Is there an *npm* command to prevent the accumulation of, or clean out, cloned git repositories?

Or do we just need to have the Temp folder cleaned out every once in a while?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found an npm way to do this.

So we just have a PowerShell script clear out any `%AppData%\Temp\npm*` folders.